# Passing Geometry object to processing tool instead of Layer

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, qgis-processing

In ArcPy, you can pass a geometry object as parameter to geoprocessing tool:

```py
import arcpy

coordinates = [[20, 30], [30, 30], [30, 20], [20, 20]]
array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(x, y) for x, y in coordinates])

# Create a polygon geometry object using the array object
boundary = arcpy.Polygon(array, arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))

arcpy.Clip_analysis('c:/data/rivers.shp', 
                     boundary, # <- GEOMETRY OBJECT
                    'c:/data/rivers_clipped.shp')
```

I have a polygon geometry and a layer. I want to clip the layer by the polygon geometry using PyQGIS. Normally, I make a new layer, add the geometry to the layer and use it in `processing.run` as follows:

```py
coordinates = [QgsPointXY(20, 30), QgsPointXY(30, 30),
               QgsPointXY(30, 20), QgsPointXY(20, 20)]
geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([coordinates ])

temp_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326", "TEST", "memory")

feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(geometry)
temp_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
temp_layer.updateExtents()

LayerA = iface.activeLayer()

result = processing.run("native:difference",
                        {'INPUT': LayerA,       # <- QgsVectorLayer
                         'OVERLAY': temp_layer, # <- QgsVectorLayer
                         'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

**But** I would like to avoid making a new layer for one geometry. I tried passing a geometry to `processing.run`, but it obviously didn't work:

```py
result = processing.run("native:difference",
                        {'INPUT': LayerA,       # <- QgsVectorLayer
                         'OVERLAY': geometry,   # <- QgsGeometry ?
                         'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

How can I pass a geometry object to a processing tool without making a new layer for the geometry? Is that possible in PyQGIS?

Comment: This something I have wondered too. Currently I have a function, `geom2lyr` to convert a geometry or list of geometries into a layer, in a library that I import into most of my scripts. Using the geometry directly would be very handy.

Answer (score 4):

When I check the help for the [`"native:difference"`/`"qgis:difference"`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) algorithm with `processing.algorithmHelp("native:difference")` it declares that:

```
INPUT: Input layer

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource

    Accepted data types:
        - str: layer ID
        - str: layer name
        - str: layer source
        - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition
        - QgsProperty
        - QgsVectorLayer
```

*where:*

- [`QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition.html) : a constructor for `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`, accepting a static string `source`.
- [`QgsProperty`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Property/QgsProperty.html) : a constructor for a `QgsAbstractProperty`. The property will be set to an InvalidProperty type.
- [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html) : represents a vector layer which manages a vector based data sets.

So, it seems there is **no possibility** to pass directly the geometry object to processing algorithm.

However, I can suggest an alternative that uses a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers):

```py
coordinates1 = [QgsPointXY(20, 30), QgsPointXY(30, 30), QgsPointXY(30, 20), QgsPointXY(20, 20)]
coordinates2 = [QgsPointXY(25, 35), QgsPointXY(35, 35), QgsPointXY(35, 25), QgsPointXY(25, 25)]

geometry1 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([coordinates1])
geometry2 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([coordinates2])

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer( f"?query=SELECT ST_GeomFromText('{geometry1.asWkt()}')", "vlayer1", "virtual" )
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer( f"?query=SELECT ST_GeomFromText('{geometry2.asWkt()}')", "vlayer2", "virtual" )

result = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:difference",
                        {'INPUT': layer1, # <- QgsVectorLayer
                         'OVERLAY': layer2, # <- QgsVectorLayer
                         'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

If it is not mandatory to use the ["Difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) tool one can also try this:

```py
coordinates1 = [QgsPointXY(20, 30), QgsPointXY(30, 30), QgsPointXY(30, 20), QgsPointXY(20, 20)]
coordinates2 = [QgsPointXY(25, 35), QgsPointXY(35, 35), QgsPointXY(35, 25), QgsPointXY(25, 25)]

geometry1 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([coordinates1])
geometry2 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([coordinates2])
                
difference_geometry = geometry1.difference(geometry2)

result = QgsVectorLayer( f"?query=SELECT ST_GeomFromText('{difference_geometry.asWkt()}')", "result", "virtual" )

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result)
```

---

**References:**

- [Creating Virtual Layer programmatically in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227203/creating-virtual-layer-programmatically-in-qgis)
- [Visualising WKT geometry string in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/visualising-wkt-geometry-string-in-qgis/318483#318483)
- [Doing difference between two layers in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336117/doing-difference-between-two-layers-in-pyqgis)